# Draw text on shape in ActionScript 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, text, shapes, displayobject

Is there any way to draw text in a DisplayObject or Shape using only ActionScript? The only way I can find on the web is by creating a TextField, but I can't add a TF to a DisplayObject or Shape.

**Edit:**

Solved thanks to [viatropos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340525/draw-text-on-shape-in-actionscript-3/2340543#2340543).

For anyone that's interested:

`DisplayObject` implements `IBitmapDrawable` which can be passed as an argument to the `draw` function of a `BitmapData` object, which then can be drawn using `graphics.beginBitmapFill`.

```
var textfield:TextField = new TextField;
textfield.text = "text";

var bitmapdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData(theWidth, theHeight, true, 0x00000000);
bitmapdata.draw(textfield);

graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapdata);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight);
graphics.endFill();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question.  This is beyond anything I've ever needed to do, but I think I know how to do it.

Shape extends DisplayObject, but not DisplayObjectContainer, so you can't add anything to it.  But it *does* have the `graphics` property, so you can draw things into it.  The best way I can think of is to take a Bitmap snapshot of the TextField, and draw that into the Shape.  I know this is what Degrafa does for their [RasterText](http://www.degrafa.org/blog/tag/raster-text/) (check out the [source](http://code.google.com/p/degrafa/source/browse/branches/Origin/Degrafa/com/degrafa/geometry/RasterText.as), it's really helpful).

If you changed your Shape to a Sprite instead, it's a lot easier.  Sprite extends DisplayObjectContainer, so you could add your TextField there.

Hope that helps,
Lance